# Spring Boot -> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; For input string: "create"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em Spring Boot para gerenciamento de biblioteca.

E no momento que eu tento fazer uma nova criação de usuário usando a anotação @PostMapping, está me retornando o seguinte erro:

```
2023-03-09T16:24:18.454-03:00  WARN 11844 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; For input string: "create"]
```

Abaixo está as classes de User e UserController:

**User.class**

```
package com.github.nibiroo.library_management.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "phone_number")
private String phoneNumber;

@Column(name = "CPF")
private String CPF;


public User() {
}
public User(String name, String email, String phoneNumber, String CPF) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.CPF = CPF;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}
public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
public String getCPF() {
    return CPF;
}
public void setCPF(String CPF) {
    this.CPF = CPF;
}
}
```

**UserControler.class**

```
package com.github.nibiroo.library_management.controller;

import com.github.nibiroo.library_management.entity.User;
import com.github.nibiroo.library_management.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> findAllUsers() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userRepository.findAll());
}

@GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<User> findUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {

    Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findById(id);

    return optionalUser.map(ResponseEntity::ok).orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}

@PutMapping(value = "/edit/{id}",  consumes = {"application/json"})
public ResponseEntity<User> updateUserById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long idParam, @RequestBody User userRequestBody) {

    Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findById(idParam);

    if (optionalUser.isEmpty()){
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

    User existingUser = optionalUser.get();
    existingUser.setName(userRequestBody.getName());
    existingUser.setEmail(userRequestBody.getEmail());
    existingUser.setPhoneNumber(userRequestBody.getPhoneNumber());

    userRepository.save(existingUser);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(existingUser);
}

@PostMapping("/create")
public User postUser(@RequestBody User userRequestBody){
    return userRepository.save(userRequestBody);
}
}
```

Não consigo entender o que ele está tentando converter de String para Long, sendo que até olhando os mappings anteriores, o Long é um parâmetro que faz referência ao id, porém, no insert o banco irá fazer este auto_increment. Podem me ajudar, por gentileza?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: **RESOLVIDO**

Ao fazer a requisição da API via Postman, por padrão o Content-Type: text/plain, e por isso ele reclama sobre a conversão!

Para sua devida correção, foi necessário forçar que o Content-Type: application/json

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**RESOLVIDO**

Ao fazer a requisição da API via Postman, por padrão o Content-Type: text/plain, e por isso ele reclama sobre a conversão!
[Content-Type: text/plain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ssqb.png)

Para sua devida correção, foi necessário forçar que o Content-Type: application/json
[Content-Type: application/json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhaRG.png)